# Emacs django-mode does not detect virtualenv

Tags: emacs

I am new to emacs, but I know how to navigate the basics.
I simply want Django integration with emacs 24 on ubuntu.
Django-mode seems to be the only game in town, but is there a tutorial that is written with more complete steps?  A typical use case would be someone who is not an expert in emacs, but wants to add Django support to emacs.

I have virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper all set up properly.  But django-mode is not detecting my virtualenv no matter what I do.
I have a great deal of trouble with the quoted paragraph below on Directory local variables as the documentation is poorly written.
Is this  file .dir-locals.el optional?  Many of his explanations are confusing.  Do I need iPython? I would think not, but I'm guessing the python-shell-interpreter is not optional. 
I have made a .dir-locals.el file and added my virtualenv path, but django-mode is not detecting my virtualenv. In emacs it says: virtualenv none.

There are also screenshots of a menu bar that allows alot of neat stuff like running ./manage.py collectstatic, etc....but no mention of how to activate the menu.  Maybe this is a basic emacs command but I don't know it and would appreciate it if someone could show me how to set up emacs with django.

Are there any other alternatives or is django mode the way to go?  Did I miss a huge chunk of documentation (like is it hiding inside emacs)

Thanks!

> Directory Local variables Now we have all set there's a really
>   important topic to talk about and that's Directory Local Variables.
>
> python.el is directory local variables aware and is in favor of
>   directory based configurations, that's why understanding this topic is
>   that important. So I suggest you to read the relevant part of the
>   manual with M-: (info "(emacs)Directory Variables").
>
> The .dir-locals.el is a file which contains an Association List, but
>   don't let the name scare you, the following is a quite complete
>   example of what I'm using to open the current project.
>
> ((python-mode   (python-shell-interpreter . "python")
>   (python-shell-interpreter-args .
>   "/home/fgallina/Code/Projects/anue-site/anue/manage.py shell")
>   (python-shell-prompt-regexp . "In \[[0-9]+\]: ")
>   (python-shell-prompt-output-regexp . "Out\[[0-9]+\]: ")
>   (python-shell-completion-setup-code . "from IPython.core.completerlib
>   import module_completion")
>   (python-shell-completion-module-string-code .
>   "';'.join(module_completion('''%s'''))\n")
>   (python-shell-completion-string-code .
>   "';'.join(get_ipython().Completer.all_completions('''%s'''))\n")
>   (python-shell-extra-pythonpaths
>   "/home/fgallina/Code/Projects/anue-site/anue/apps/")
>   (python-shell-virtualenv-path . "/home/fgallina/.virtualenvs/anue")))

http://from-the-cloud.com/en/emacs/2013/01/28_emacs-as-a-django-ide-with-python-djangoel.html

Comment: Which dango-mode?  Why virtualenv?  Why directory-local variables?

Comment: python-django.el is what I'm trying to integrate into emacs 24. I use the terminal.  Nevermind,I've spent 24 actual working hours on this.  I usually blame myself since clearly other people can make this work.  But for me, without clearer documentation, I will be unable to get this to work.  I'll look into other options, but if anyone could put together a tutorial for newbies, I'd be most appreciative!

Comment: Then tell us what you have done, and how it failed.

Answer (score 0):

There was recent a question at `Help-gnu-emacs@gnu.org` whose answers pertains to your case also

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2013-06/msg00425.html

WRT this answer only replace Pymacs by django-mode.

For the moment, just use Emacs as editor. Otherwise see some risk to end up in frustration.

IPython is great to learn Python itself, basically it provides an enhanced interactive shell. On IPython is built Enthought -- a Python Distribution providing scientists with a comprehensive set of tools to perform rigorous data analysis and visualization.

Don't see it related to Django so far.